# Subset pandas dataframe by dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with a column, call it `A`, that contains multiple data types. I want to select all rows of `df` where `A` has a particular data type.

For example, suppose that `A` has types `int` and `str`. I want to do something like `df[type(df[A])==int]` .

Answer (score 4):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['hello', 1, 2, 3, 'bad']})
```

This entire column will be assigned `dtype` `Object`.  If you just want to find numeric values:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').dropna()
```

```
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

*However*, this would also allow floats, string representations of numbers, etc. into the mix.  If you really want to find elements that are of `type` `int`, you can use a list comprehension:

```
df.loc[[isinstance(val, int) for val in df.A], 'A']
```

```
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: A, dtype: object
```

But notice that the `dtype` is still `Object`.

---

If the column has Boolean values, these will be kept, since `bool` is a subclass of `int`.  If you *don't* want this behavior, you can use `type` instead of `isinstance`

Answer (score 4):

#### Group by `type`

```
dod = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['A'].map(type), sort=False)))
```

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 'one', {1}, [1], (1,)] * 2))
```

#### Validation

```
for t, d in dod.items():
    print(t, d, sep='\n')
    print()

<class 'int'>
   A
0  1
5  1

<class 'str'>
     A
1  one
6  one

<class 'set'>
     A
2  {1}
7  {1}

<class 'list'>
     A
3  [1]
8  [1]

<class 'tuple'>
      A
4  (1,)
9  (1,)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `groupby` data from user3483203

```
for _,x in df.groupby(df.A.apply(lambda x : type(x).__name__)):
    print(x)

   A
1  1
2  2
3  3
       A
0  hello
4    bad

d={ y:x   for y,x in df.groupby(df.A.apply(lambda x : type(x).__name__))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2, 'B',3.0, 'c', 1, 'a', 2.0, 'b',3, 'C', 'A', 1.0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": a})

df['upper'] = df['a'].str.isupper()
df['lower'] = df['a'].str.islower()
df['int'] = df['a'].apply(isinstance,args = [int])
df['float'] = df['a'].apply(isinstance,args = [float])

print(df)

    a   upper   lower   int     float
0   2   NaN      NaN    True    False
1   B   True    False   False   False
2   3   NaN      NaN    False   True
3   c   False   True    False   False
4   1   NaN      NaN    True    False
5   a   False   True    False   False
6   2   NaN      NaN    False   True
7   b   False   True    False   False
8   3   NaN      NaN    True    False
9   C   True    False   False   False
10  A   True    False   False   False
11  1   NaN      NaN    False   True

integer = df[df['int']]['a']

print(integer)

0    2
4    1
8    3
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Your code might be helpful, but it would be nice if you explain your answer, how your code works and why it is useful.

Comment: @Ivanhercaz is that the reason you down-vote the answer.!? The code is not a new package or a huge program to be explained! it is self explanatory.

Comment: Hi @Khalil! First of all, yes, this is the reason why I down-vote the answer. And the reason why I wrote a comment was to explained this situation, because I assumed in good faith that you wanted to help the user who ask this question. But this is my criterion to down-vote, if you have another is totally respectful. A down-vote doesn't mean that you are a bad user or something else! Please, don't hesitate about it, my intention wasn't disturb or harm your reputation. I could down-vote and didn't write a comment, but I prefer to write you an explanation because it's the fairest to you.